# HOW to work with NULL in a NOT NULL column?

Tags: t-sql, null

I have a column that is specifyed as (int, not null).
I've been trying to insert NULL for the missing records of that column,
can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: There are two solutions. First of them - alter column allowing NULLs. Second - select another value that will mean that the value is missing (for example, 0, -1 or max_int).

Answer (score 2):

No you cant insert `NULL` in a `NON NULL` column. That's what constraints are for.

If you want, you can alter the column.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable
ALTER COLUMN column_a INT NULL
```

Or just insert 0 for each record you don't want to have a value.

Though be aware on the difference of NULL and blank/zero values.